# About character string formatting of date

Tags: ios, swift

This function gets the tapped date when tapping the calendar date.
What I want to realize is, for example, when I tap 2018/11/1, I want to get the string "2018/11/01", but I do not know how to do it. Could you tell me?

```
func getDay(_ date:Date) -> (Int,Int,Int,String){

    let tmpCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)

    let Component = tmpCalendar.component(.weekday, from: date)

    let weekName = Component - 1

    let formatter = DateFormatter()

    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ja")

    let year = tmpCalendar.component(.year, from: date)

    let month = tmpCalendar.component(.month, from: date)

    let day = tmpCalendar.component(.day, from: date)

    return (year,month,day,formatter.shortWeekdaySymbols[weekName])

}

func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition){

    let selectDay = getDay(date)

    let scheduleForDate = "\(String(selectDay.0))/\(String(selectDay.1))/\(String(selectDay.2))"
    print(scheduleForDate)

    getStartScheduleDate(date: scheduleForDate)

    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

By the way, the library I am using is FSCalendar.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `DateFormatter` set to the format you want.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
let result = formatter.string(from: someDate)
```

But it's not a good idea to use such a format to show dates to a user. It's ambiguous. Is that November 1st or January 11th?

It's better to use a date style so the date is shown to the user in their own expected format given their locale.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .short
let result = formatter.string(from: someDate)
```

Or at least localize the specific format:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("yyyyMMdd")
let result = formatter.string(from: someDate)
```

Comment: I see! It helped! Thank you very much.